# Calculate the address of the subnet

Tags: python

Calculate the address of the subnet:

COMMAND:
If you represent the host address and netmask as lists of 4 numbers each, you may take the bitwise AND of the first number from one list and the first number from the other list, followed by the bitwise AND of the second number from the one list and the bitwise AND of the second number from the other list, and so on. Returns the address of the network as a list.

MY CODE:

```
def apply_network_mask(host_address, netmask):
    ips = host_address.split(".")
    net = netmask.split(".")

    ips_bin = [format(int(i), '08b') for i in ips]
    net_bin = [format(int(i), '08b') for i in net]

    print(f"{ips_bin & net_bin}")
```

My Code:
[image: My Code]

what I need:
apply_network_mask ([192,168,0,191], [255,255,255,0]) I should get back [192,168,0,0]

Comment: So if you're supposed to return the address of the network as a list, why aren't you returning anything?

Comment: Also `ips-Bin` is not `ips_bin`.

Comment: yea i have changed it but still need help

Comment: You've edited out the typo that caused the error in your screenshot. So what is your question?

Comment: What’s your input? What’s your actual vs. desired output? What’s your question? Don’t post images of code. Paste text into question.

Comment: i need to get the address of the subnet.

Comment: apply_network_mask ([192,168,0,191], [255,255,255,0]) I should get back [192,168,0,0]

Comment: Your code expects strings, not lists.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Seriously: code is text, so show it as text, not as screen shot. And dont come in and rework crucial parts of your question later on like this, in a way that changes context completely.

Answer (score 0):

look at this example

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Address
import re


class MyIPv4(IPv4Address):
    def __and__(self, other: IPv4Address):
        if not isinstance(other, (int, IPv4Address)):
            raise NotImplementedError
        return self.__class__(int(self) & int(other))

    @property
    def binary_repr(self, sep=".") -> str:
        """Represent IPv4 in binary"""
        return sep.join(f"{i:08b}" for i in self.packed)  

    @classmethod
    def from_binary_repr(cls, binary_repr: str):
        """Represent IPv4 ifrom binary to human readable view"""
        i = int(re.sub(r"[^01]", "", binary_repr), 2)  
        return cls(i)


addr = MyIPv4("192.168.0.2")
mask = MyIPv4("255.255.255.0")


print(f'{addr} & {mask} is {addr & mask} network')
print(f'{addr.binary_repr} & {mask.binary_repr} is {(addr & mask).binary_repr} network')
```

[source](https://realpython.com/python-ipaddress-module/)

Comment: Please give attribution when you copy code from another source.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one go by reading the `network` property of an [`ipaddress.ip_interface`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.ip_interface)

```py
>>> import ipaddress
>>> ipaddress.ip_interface("192.168.0.161/255.255.255.0").network
IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/24')
```

You can go further and directly get your network address as a string from the `IPv4Network`'s `with_netmask` property

```py
>>> ipaddress.ip_interface("192.168.0.161/255.255.255.0").network.with_netmask.split('/')
['192.168.0.0', '255.255.255.0']
```

This will also work for IPv6 addresses

```py
>>> ipaddress.ip_interface("2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334/64").network
IPv6Network('2001:db8:85a3::/64')
```